# jquery droppable loses its original class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, droppable

I need to get elements id and class when something is dropped on it. Id works fine, but class is not passed...

HTML

```
<div id="drag" class="two">drag</div>
<div id="drop" class="one">drop</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#drag").draggable();
    $("#drop").droppable({
        drop: function(){
            alert(this.class+" "+this.id)
        }
    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skunksts/U5RjC/)

Comment: editted comment and added fiddle

Comment: Not advisable to retrive class. Because jQueryUI will add their own classes to the DOM object

Comment: what could i use instead of class? I need to get 2 unique attributes of each droppable.

Comment: perhaps you might wan to consider using HTML5's `data-*` attribute.
go google it to see how it's used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/FLLaj/

As mentioned. when Draggable is dropped, it retrieved the class. but there's 2 classes.
A much proper way of doing is to use `data-*` attribute introduced in HTML5

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#drag").draggable({revert: true})
        $("#drop").droppable({
            drop: function(){
                alert($(this).attr('class')+" "+$(this).attr('id'))
            }})
       })
```

Comment: Thank you jinyuan. data- atribute makes sense. I will investigate it further :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no `class` property - use `className` to retrieve the class. But as has been noted in the comments, jQuery UI adds its own classes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of class you can use any rel attributes.Because class names are not unique.For Example

```
<div id="drag" class="two" rel="u1">drag</div>
<div id="drop" class="one"rel="u2">drop</div>

JS COde:
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#drag").draggable({revert: true})
 $("#drop").droppable({
    drop: function(){
        alert($(this).attr('rel'));
    }})
})
```

Link [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/U5RjC/3/)

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using this. `rel` attribute has it's own purpose and using it for anything else is inappropriate. But it's a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#drag").draggable({revert: true})
   $("#drop").droppable({
       drop: function(event,ui){
           console.log(ui.draggable.attr('class'));
           console.log($(this).attr('class'));
       }
   });
});
```

modified your code.check if it works